# My elif statements are having syntax errors -python

Tags: python, sms

I'm making a menu based tool and when the interpreter gets to the 3rd elif (4th option) it gives me a syntax error.

I am using debians vim command to code.
Here is the error:

```
 elif (sel == "3"):
    ^^^^
```

I tried:

```
elif (sel == "4"):
        toat = "txt.att.net"
        with open(eee.txt) as fp:
            msg = EmailMessage()
            msg.set_content(fp.read())
        msg['Subject'] = f'The contents of {eee.txt}'
        msg['From'] = fromail
        msg['To'] = victim
        s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    #Main set-up complete time for spam
        def spam():
            s.send_message(msg)
            return spam()
        def spam2():
            s.send_message(msg)
            s.send_message(msg)
            spam()
            return spam2()
        def spam3():
            s.send_message(msg)
            s.send_message(msg)
            s.send_message(msg)
            spam2()
            return spam3()
        for i in range(1,17):
            TrueSpam = threading.Thread(target = spam3)
            x.start()
```

But I only got the error i mentioned earlier. I made as many many edits as I could find but none worked.

heres the whole piece of code:

```
HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
CARRIERS = ["verizon", "tmobile", "sprint", "atnt", "boost", "cricket", "uscellular", "mint"]
CARRIER_ADRESSES = ["vtext.com", "tmomail.net", "messaging.sprintpcs.com", "txt.att.net", "smsmyboostmobile.com", "sms.cricketwireless.net", "email.uscc.net"]
toat = ""
target = input("Target Phone Number")
fromail = input("Your Email")
victim = (target,"@",toat)
#set up vars and lists
menu = True
while menu:
    print("[1] verizon")
    print("[2] tmobile")
    print("[3] sprint")
    print("[4] atnt")
    print("[5] boost")
    print("[6] cricket")
    print("[7] uscellular")
    print("[8] mint")
#Carrier Menu
    sel = input("Select Carrier")
    if (sel == "1"):
        toat = "vtext.com"
        with open(eee.txt) as fp:
            msg = EmailMessage()
            msg.set_content(fp.read())
        msg['Subject'] = f'The contents of {eee.txt}'
        msg['From'] = fromail
        msg['To'] = victim
        s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    #Main set-up complete time for spam
        def spam():
            s.send_message(msg)
            return spam()
        def spam2():
            s.send_message(msg)
            s.send_message(msg)
            spam()
            return spam2()
        def spam3():
            s.send_message(msg)
            s.send_message(msg)
            s.send_message(msg)
            spam2()
            return spam3()
        for i in range(1,17):
            TrueSpam = threading.Thread(target = spam3)
            x.start()
    elif (sel == "2"):
        toat = "tmomail.net"
        with open(eee.txt) as fp:
            msg = EmailMessage()
            msg.set_content(fp.read())
        msg['Subject'] = f'The contents of {eee.txt}'
        msg['From'] = fromail
        msg['To'] = victim
        s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    #Main set-up complete time for spam
        def spam():
            s.send_message(msg)
            return spam()
        def spam2():
            s.send_message(msg)
            s.send_message(msg)
            spam()
            return spam2()
        def spam3():
            s.send_message(msg)
            s.send_message(msg)
            s.send_message(msg)
            spam2()
            return spam3()
        for i in range(1,17):
            TrueSpam = threading.Thread(target = spam3)
            x.start()
        elif (sel == "3"):
        toat = "messaging.sprintpcs.com"
        with open(eee.txt) as fp:
            msg = EmailMessage()
            msg.set_content(fp.read())
        msg['Subject'] = f'The contents of {eee.txt}'
        msg['From'] = fromail
        msg['To'] = victim
        s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    #Main set-up complete time for spam
    def spam():
            s.send_message(msg)
            return spam()
    def spam2():
            s.send_message(msg)
            s.send_message(msg)
            spam()
            return spam2()
    def spam3():
            s.send_message(msg)
            s.send_message(msg)
            s.send_message(msg)
            spam2()
            return spam3()
    for i in range(1,17):
            TrueSpam = threading.Thread(target = spam3)
            x.start()
    elif (sel == "4"):
        toat = "txt.att.net"
        with open(eee.txt) as fp:
            msg = EmailMessage()
            msg.set_content(fp.read())
        msg['Subject'] = f'The contents of {eee.txt}'
        msg['From'] = fromail
        msg['To'] = victim
        s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    #Main set-up complete time for spam
        def spam():
            s.send_message(msg)
            return spam()
        def spam2():
            s.send_message(msg)
            s.send_message(msg)
            spam()
            return spam2()
        def spam3():
            s.send_message(msg)
            s.send_message(msg)
            s.send_message(msg)
            spam2()
            return spam3()
        for i in range(1,17):
            TrueSpam = threading.Thread(target = spam3)
            x.start()
    elif (sel == "5"):
        toat = "smsmyboostmobile.com"
        with open(eee.txt) as fp:
            msg = EmailMessage()
            msg.set_content(fp.read())
        msg['Subject'] = f'The contents of {eee.txt}'
        msg['From'] = fromail
        msg['To'] = victim
        s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    #Main set-up complete time for spam
        def spam():
            s.send_message(msg)
            return spam()
        def spam2():
            s.send_message(msg)
            s.send_message(msg)
            spam()
            return spam2()
        def spam3():
            s.send_message(msg)
            s.send_message(msg)
            s.send_message(msg)
            spam2()
            return spam3()
        for i in range(1,17):
            TrueSpam = threading.Thread(target = spam3)
            x.start()
    elif (sel == "6"):
        toat = "sms.cricketwireless.net"
        with open(eee.txt) as fp:
            msg = EmailMessage()
            msg.set_content(fp.read())
        msg['Subject'] = f'The contents of {eee.txt}'
        msg['From'] = fromail
        msg['To'] = victim
        s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    #Main set-up complete time for spam
        def spam():
            s.send_message(msg)
            return spam()
        def spam2():
            s.send_message(msg)
            s.send_message(msg)
            spam()
            return spam2()
        def spam3():
            s.send_message(msg)
            s.send_message(msg)
            s.send_message(msg)
            spam2()
            return spam3()
        for i in range(1,17):
            TrueSpam = threading.Thread(target = spam3)
            x.start()
    elif (sel == "7"):
        toat = "email.uscc.net"
        with open(eee.txt) as fp:
            msg = EmailMessage()
            msg.set_content(fp.read())
        msg['Subject'] = f'The contents of {eee.txt}'
        msg['From'] = fromail
        msg['To'] = victim
        s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    #Main set-up complete time for spam
        def spam():
            s.send_message(msg)
            return spam()
        def spam2():
            s.send_message(msg)
            s.send_message(msg)
            spam()
            return spam2()
        def spam3():
            s.send_message(msg)
            s.send_message(msg)
            s.send_message(msg)
            spam2()
            return spam3()
        for i in range(1,17):
            TrueSpam = threading.Thread(target = spam3)
            x.start()
    elif (sel == "8"):
        toat = "tmomail.net"
        with open(eee.txt) as fp:
            msg = EmailMessage()
            msg.set_content(fp.read())
        msg['Subject'] = f'The contents of {eee.txt}'
        msg['From'] = fromail
        msg['To'] = victim
    s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
#Main set-up complete time for spam
```

Comment: "heres the error"—that's not the error, it's a tiny part of the error. Please always share _complete, exact_ error messages.

Comment: Where is the `if` statement that that `elif` supposed to follow? Why are you defining so many functions inside an `if` statement? Indentation is significant in Python, and I don't think this indentation is dong what you want / expect it to.

Comment: You have infinite recursion in all your `spamX()` functions. Luckily you never call them.

Comment: `elif (sel == "3"):` is indented too far. It needs to be at the same indentation as `elif (sel == "2"):`

Comment: Thank you guys when i shared my error that was the whole error except SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I think you need to read up on the purpose of functions and how to use them. Your code could make use of a properly designed function, which could reduce the repetitiveness within your code.

Comment: I was going to use functions but i made the (as you pointed out) poor decision to copy and paste the same piece of code 8 times

Comment: Also i did intend to infinitely call my functions

Comment: thank you to reminding me that functions exist it made the code much easier to read and now works except for the smtp server and my laptop broke and i had to flash linux